# How can I make a sum of numbers in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, sum

How can I make a for-loop which calculates the sum of all numbers from 1 to 100 and continuously stores it in sum. That is the for loop must go from 1 to 100 inclusive?

```js
let sum = 0;

for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  sum = sum + i;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. Here is some [documentation for loops/iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) in case you're stuck.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to programming. This is my attempt:

Comment: let sum = 0;

for(let i = 0; i >= 100; i++) {
    sum=i+1;
}

Comment: `let sum = 0; for(let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) sum += i;`

Comment: `for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++)` - because you want to run numbers between 1 and 100, and `sum = sum + i` to add the current number to the sum. Good luck with the coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop condition should be `<` instead of `>=` and within the loop you need to take the last value of `sum` and add `i` to it. Lastly, if you want the sum of numbers from 1 to 100, then your loop has to start at 1 and end at 100.

```js
let sum = 0;

for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
  sum = sum + i;
}

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works. I have never used console.log before. How does it work?

Comment: @Anna You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote and mark as "the" answer. `console..log()` is just an instruction to print whatever you tell it to print, in the browsers console, which is part of its developer tools and is accessible via F12.